# How can I make RoutedUICommand.OnCanExecute for a command assigned to a button depend on Keyboard.FocusedElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, routed-commands

I have a question regarding `RoutedUICommand.OnCanExecute` and `Keyboard.FocusedElement`.

I 've created a command with an `InputGesture` (keyboard short-cut), assigned it to a `MenuItem` or `Button` and added it to the owning window's `CommandBindings` with the following positive results:

- The buttons/menus are disabled, if the `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is not a `DataGridCell`.
- I can click on the menu and the command is executed, the focused `DataGridCell` remains focused.
- I can use the keyboard short-cut and the command is executed, if the focus is on a `DataGridCell`.

What I am not able to resolve is the following issue:

- I cannot trigger the command by clicking on the button, because (apparently) the click causes `OnCanExecute` to fail, because `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is then the button.

Strangely, though: if I disable the `OnCanExecute` method by always setting `e.CanExecute = true`, the above problem does not come up and within `OnExecuted` `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is indeed the `DataGridCell`.

Of all the sites I visited in search for a solution I found https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2009/03/20/icommand-is-like-a-chocolate-cake/ very interesting (esp. *ToolBar is a “focus scope”*), but it wasn't enough to help me resolve my issue.

Here are the relevant (and abbreviated) code snippets.

A command that is supposed to work with a currently selected `DataGridCell`:

```
public class MyDataGridCellCommand : RoutedUICommand
{
    public MyDataGridCellCommand()
    {
        this.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.F1));
        this.Text = "Process selected cell";
    }

    public void OnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Keyboard.FocusedElement is DataGridCell cell){
            //Process selected cell...
        }
    }

    public void OnCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = (Keyboard.FocusedElement is DataGridCell);
    }
}
```

The window's Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem x:Name="menuTest"></MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--Button in "default" stackpanel -->
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                    <Button x:Name ="btnTest1" Content="Test1"/>
                </StackPanel>

               <!--Button in "focus scope" stackpanel -->
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" >
                    <Button x:Name ="btnTest2" Content="Test2"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--Button in toolbar-->
                <ToolBar x:Name ="toolBar1" Focusable="True">
                    <Button x:Name ="btnTest3" Content="Test3" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                </ToolBar>
            </StackPanel>

            <DataGrid>
                <!--Layout Attributes removed for brevity. -->
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The window's code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var cmd = new MyDataGridCellCommand();

        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(cmd, cmd.OnExecuted, cmd.OnCanExecute));

        this.btnTest1.Command = cmd;
        this.btnTest2.Command = cmd;
        this.btnTest3.Command = cmd;
        this.menuTest.Command = cmd;

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the focus on the test button I would just set Focusable="False" on btnTest1.

If you still want to have the button focusable, one idea could be not to use Keyboard.FocusedElement but the [FocusManager.GetFocusedElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.focusmanager.getfocusedelement?view=netframework-4.7.2) like this:

```
public class MyDataGridCellCommand : RoutedUICommand
{
    public MyDataGridCellCommand()
    {
        this.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.F1));
        this.Text = "Process selected cell";

    }

    public void OnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(sender as DependencyObject) is DataGridCell) {
            //Process selected cell...
        }
    }

    public void OnCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(sender as DependencyObject) is DataGridCell);
    }
}
```